# New GKE nodes are unable to pull images from Container Registry on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I have a GKE cluster on GCP with 2 existing node pools. I'm trying to create a new node pool:

[image: node pools]

Any new node pools I create are unable to pull containers from Container Registry with the following error:

[image: error message]

The settings and service account I'm using for the new node pool are exactly the same as the existing node pools (other than machine type):

[image: node settings]

Everything is working as expected on the existing node pools, but each time I create a new node pool I'm having the same problem:

[image]

The logs show the following error on image pull:

> E0128 06:44:03.656599    1763 remote_image.go:242] "PullImage from image service failed" err="rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "eu.gcr.io/{PROJECT}/{IMAGE}@sha256:*****": failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: could not fetch content descriptor sha256:***** (application/vnd.docker.container.image.v1+json) from remote: not found" image="eu.gcr.io/{PROJECT}/{IMAGE}@sha256:*****"

Comment: how big is the container image you are pulling? I noticed that the new node pool is e2-micro. Have you tried to create the same e2-medium node and verify the same ImagePullErr? Can you post the logs on image pull? 
resource.type="k8s_node"
resource.labels.node_name="new_node_name"
"PullImage" "image_name"

Comment: The container is 244 MB. I have tried creating a new e2-medium node pool and got the same error.

I've updated the question to show the image pull logs.

Comment: I have also tried selecting a different service account when creating the node pool and still got the same error.

Comment: Can you pull the image from the new GKE node? Run `docker pull {image_name}:tag`. Also, are you running private GKE cluster and do you have VPC-SC set up? btw, container registry is deprecating this May, you might to consider switching to Artifact registry.

Comment: Switching to Artifact Registry resolved this problem for me and I'm able to pull docker images without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As per the [container registry official doc](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication), Container Registry is deprecated. After May 15, 2024. Artifact Registry will host images for the [gcr.io](http://gcr.io) domain in projects without previous Container Registry usage Starting January 8, 2024, if your organization has not previously used Container Registry, new [gcr.io](http://gcr.io) repositories will be hosted on Artifact Registry by default. For more information on this change, see [gcr.io hosted on Artifact Registry](http://gcr.io).
- As per the log from pull image error  **failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: could not fetch content descriptor sha256:** seems that this might be due to image tag typo error and also Skaffold is not supporting the correct tag. As per the [Skaffold documentation](https://skaffold.dev/docs/taggers/), it supports multiple taggers or tag policies for tagging images. By following this Skaffold documentation add the necessary configuration in **skaffold.yaml** and give it a try.
- **Note**: Cross-check the image tags for mistakes which might be the reason for error.

Comment: Thank you - Switching to use Artifact Registry resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to use images hosted in Artifact Registry fixed this problem.

I was recieving **ErrImagePull** when using images hosted on gcr.io in my newly created node pool. Existing node pools didn't seem to be affected and I was still able to pull gcr.io images without any errors.

Images hosted in Artifact Registry are pulled without any errors in newly created node pools:

[image]